# Basic do shortcodes question

Tags: shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

I used WordPress codex page to code. As you can see I have 2 PHP codes in my line. The page is able to get the code's value but it doesn't obey the CSS rules, which I believe, because I inserted my PHP codes in the wrong way.

Can you take a look at the following code and suggest to what the problem might be?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[groups_non_member group="VPS"]' ."<p class='vod-time-price'>"   . the_field('run_t') . "MIN | $". the_field('price_per_r') ."</p>". '[/groups_non_member]'); ?>
```

Comment: What does "doesn't obey CSS rules" mean? CSS-specific questions are off-topic per the [FAQ].

Comment: Link for your reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Comment: @user3067592 Helga is no _dude_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_field()` is an ACF function and will `echo` content. It follows the WordPress (somewhat) pattern whereby functions with `the_` at the front will `echo` content and functions beginning with `get_` return content.

> Displays the value of the specified field. (this is the same as “echo
>   get_field($field_name)”)
>
> http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_field/

Using the wrong function, as you have, will cause data to output in the wrong location. Use `get_the_field()` instead.